# Does composer automatically create a vendor/autoload.php?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to get the hang of using composer as a library I've downloaded requires it.

I've run composer and all the dependencies appear to have downloaded, however the autoload file isn't present in vendor. Instead of an autoload there's a few empty folders starting from

```
vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/symfony/component
```

Is there something else I need to do?

During the composer install there was one problem encountered regarding being unable to download a file from

```
nodeload.github.com/symfony/evendispatcher/zip/SomeRandomString
```

Comment: Just tried with a different list of packages and the same thing is happening.. problem with their servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading

From this it seems as if autoload.php should be automatically created by the dependency resolve process. You might want to check your software sources deprecation status and update package manager lists if necessary (assuming you running a *nix machine). Perhaps local file permissions, as well, could be causing the write/create process to fail.